# VS Code - Unable to find and install C++ extension

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have been trying to *install* ***C++ extension*** in ***Visual Studio Code*** (*latest version*). But I am keep getting "*No extension found*".

I have tried to search a possible cause for this error but so far, I have not found any useful results.

[image: Error Message]

*What is the issue and how to resolve it ?*

Comment: Have you tried to install it from marketplace [website](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cpptools)

Comment: @leopal Yes, I have been trying to install it from marketplace, but I have got no results, as you can see in the screenshot above.

Comment: If you want it REAL easy - create a "*.c" file and visual Studio code will show you that there is a recommended Extension "C/C++".
It seems like the search sometimes hangs itself up - just "cancel" and search again - that worked for me every time.

Comment: A few hours ago the [marketplace was down](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/57851). Depending on your region it may is not up and running again.

Comment: @Thrawn It worked the easy way, thanks. But I want to know why this search field is not working like it should have. B/c I want to install some plugins as well you know.

Comment: @HaaLeo I did not know about it. But I have been stuck with this issue for past 2 days. I don't think that might be the issue since my fellow mates are able to install via marketplace just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***As mentioned in the comments,***

Sometimes, [*marketplace get offline*](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/57851) and thus cause these issues.

*However*, there is a *easy hack* for this,

*Create a `*.c` file and **VS Code** will show you that there is a recommended Extension "C/C++"*